# Spring Data REST query ignores the size option if used with page

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am seeing strange behavior in my Spring Data REST application when page size seems to be ignored when anything else is present in the query part of the URL.
My application is Spring Boot 2.2.0 and JPA repository implements JpaRepository.
When I am not using any page parameter the output is:

```
 curl http:/localhost:8081/inventory/
.....
"page" : {
"size" : 20,
"totalElements" : 27422,
"totalPages" : 1372,
"number" : 0
}
```

When I specify just the page size, it works:

```
curl http:/localhost:8081/inventory/?size=5
...
"page" : {
"size" : 5,
"totalElements" : 27422,
"totalPages" : 5485,
"number" : 0
}
```

But when I specify the page size with conjunction with page number the size is ignored:

```
curl http:/localhost:8081/inventory/?page=1&size=5
...
"page" : {
"size" : 20,
"totalElements" : 27422,
"totalPages" : 1372,
"number" : 1
}
```

I also tried to use page size with sort and it was also ignored. What could cause that behavior? The query seems to be OK because the response is also using it:

```
"next" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8081/inventory?page=2&size=20"
},
```

Comment: Can you try rolling back to an older version? Sounds like possibly a bug.

Comment: @AlanHay Rolled back to Spring Boot version 1.9 and then to 1.5. Still seeing the same issue

Comment: share the code how you are using Pageable?

Comment: Add some code then as has always worked for me.

Comment: Everything is pretty much default:

Repository:
    (@)RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "inventory", path = "inventory")
    public interface InventoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Inventory, Integer> {

     List<Inventory> findByBrand(@Param("brand") String brand);

    }

Entity:


   ( @)Data
    (@)Entity
    (@)Table(name = "inventory")
    public class Inventory implements java.io.Serializable {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = -6062508910146574743L;
 
     (@)PostLoad
    private void postLoad() {
    ....

Comment: Maybe you use poorly implemented filter which accidentally chops all the URL parameters except the first one. What happens if you change the order of the parameters?

Comment: @Selindek 1. I have no filters in my implementation. I have a bean implementing RepositoryRestConfigurer in order to restrict  HTTP verbs for other resources. Nothing for the resource I have problem with. 2. I also tried to change the order of parameters. Size is being ignored regardless if it is first, second or third parameter